# AWS Lambda in VPC with S3 and EFS random fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I have a lambda function running in VPC, with access points for EFS and S3. It works most of the time but function fails randomly (like 1 in 10 times) with error message `Error from cloudfront`. Inspecting the API Gateway logs, I find this error: `Lambda invocation failed with status: 408` and `Execution failed due to configuration error: The function couldn't connect to the Amazon EFS file system with access point arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-1:123456789:access-point/fsap-123456789`

The stack is configured that way:

I created a VPC with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/26

I created 4 subnets with CIDR block 10.0.0.x/28

2 of those subnets (availability zones A & B) are associated to the default route table created with VPC.

The 2 other subnets (availability zones A & B) are associated to a second route table that I've created.

In my serverless.yml (yes I'm using serverless framework), I associate my lambda function to the subnets associated to default table.

I create an EFS with the console and associate it to the subnets associated to the second route table. Then I create an access point for EFS in yml.

So far, so good. With EFS only my function works, I can access EFS everytime.

But then, when I create an endpoint for S3 (following this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) and associate it to my default route table, it works and my lambda function has access to S3 and EFS, but it works only like 90% of the time and I cannot figure why. I guess my network is indeed not configured correctly, and both access points conflict somehow, but what am I missing here ? Thanks.

Comment: Could this be due to the idleness timeouts discussed in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html ? 

"If your functions aren't active for a long period of time, Lambda reclaims its network interfaces, and the functions become Idle. To reactivate an idle function, invoke it. This invocation fails, and the function enters a Pending state again until a network interface is available."